# Block specific AJAX requests with browser or OS

Tags: ajax, testing

I'm trying to test a product to make sure it fails correctly and therefore want to be able to block a specific AJAX request from returning any data. I could modify the source to make the request fail but I have to prove it works without changing the code.

How could I go about blocking a specific url from returning data?

Comment: The only way I know how would be to intercept the post in fire bug. Have you tried that?

Comment: I can see the request in the XHR panel but how do I block it so it fails next time I refresh?

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) can do this.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource that will show me how? I have done some googling and havent found anything. I found a page for blocking whole domains but not specific requests.

Comment: You could use fire bug to edit the actual javascript- break point to where just before the post happens then edit the code in the firbug - and it should break

Comment: @Hello-World Tamper has worked perfectly. Do you want to write an answer suggesting it and I'll accept it?

Comment: Cool glad it worked I moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help - its a fire fox plugin - have not tried it but it looks good - it says it allows you to edit and alter requests- [addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data)